# Running help <command> and piping output to Where-Object or Select-Object returns empty rows

Tags: powershell, pipe, select-object

Running the command `help firewall | Select-Object Category`. The result is one column blank `Category`.

The strange thing is that the empty rows number represent the amount of rows that `help firewall` would result without calling piping it to `Select-Object`

Or I'm trying to filter the output of `help firewall` to return only rows with Name that starts with "Get". Running `help firewall | Where-Object Name -like "Get"` just returns nothing.

Why aren't these pipes on help working? They are working perfectly on other commands.

Powershell Version 5.1 and using default windows console.

Comment: So, `help` is an alias for `Get-Help`. But not in a standard way (try using `help help` and you'll see that there's no aliases provided). Strangely enough, when I use original one (`Get-Help`) it's behaving as expected. BTW. `-like` parameter uses wildcards. So in this situation it'd be `Where-Object Name -like "Get*"`

Comment: I forgot to include the wildcard in this post. But I figured out that help returns a string, and `Name` or `Category` are not proprites of a string. And that `get-help` behaves as expected is very confusing indeed.

Comment: It's done like that on purpose. That's why when you run one, the full help shows, vs the other one only showing parts of it first before pressing a key to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement [Zilog80's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705789/45375) with background information:

[`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) `help` reveals that **`help` is *not* a mere [*alias*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) of the [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) cmdlet, but a (built-in) [*function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions)** (submit `$function:help` to see its definition).

As you've noticed yourself:

- while `Get-Help` outputs an *object* (`[pscsustomobject]`) with *properties* that reflect help-topic metadata such as `Category`, which is then *rendered* as display text by PowerShell's output-formatting system,
- the `help` function returns *strings* - a stream of text lines representing the *rendered* help topic - of necessity.

You can observe the difference in output type by piping to the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet (`help firewall | Get-Member` vs. `Get-Help firewall | Get-Member`)

**The purpose of the `help` function is to wrap `Get-Help` with *interactive paging***, to allow convenient navigation through lengthy help topics that don't fit onto a single console (terminal) screen.

This paging is provided via an *external program* (by default, `more.com` on Windows, and `less` on Unix-like platforms, configurable via `$env:PAGER`, but only in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*), and **since PowerShell only "speaks text" when communicating with external programs, `help` must send a stream of *strings* (lines for display)** to them, which it does via
[`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) `-Stream`.

Note:

- When the external paging programs find that their stdout stream *isn't* connected to a *console* (terminal), they take no action other than simply passing the input *through* (in Unix terms, they then behave like `cat`).
- Hypothetically, the `help` function itself could determine this condition and then (a) not pipe to the paging program and (b) relay the object output by `Get-Help` as-is.<sup>[1]</sup> However, determining a command's output target from inside that command, using PowerShell code, may not even be possible.

---

<sup>[1] The function actually already takes this action when a *custom* pager defined via `$env:PAGER` is found to be a *PowerShell* command rather than an external program.</sup>

Comment: Very nice and well redacted answer. To add a funny note, if `help` is a built-in function, `man` is an alias for `help` ^^

Comment: Thanks, @Zilog80. Re `man`  :) I'd never noticed that. Note that it _isn't_ an alias on Unix-like platforms, so as not to shadow the standard `man` utility there.

Comment: This give me the following idea: `New-Alias more Select-Object`, and now `help firewall` will behave like `Get-Help` :D

Comment: @Zilog80 :) It's actually even simpler: `New-Alias help Get-Help`, which relies on [aliases having higher precedence than functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence).

Answer (score 2):

Check the feedback from `help help` in PowerShell :

```
    You can also type `help` or `man`, which displays one screen of text at a
    time. Or, ` -?`, that is identical to `Get-Help`, but only
    works for cmdlets.
```

The `help`command display *"screen of text"* which means it is outputting `[System.String]` objects, not `[PSCustomObject]` objects.

Only `-?` will behave identically to `Get-help` and will provide `[PSCustomObject]` objects.

To see what's going on, check the different output from :

```
help firewall | %{ $_.GetType() }
```

And

```
Get-help firewall | %{ $_.GetType() }
```

And, for cmdlet,

```
Select-Object -? | %{ $_.gettype() }
```